# Detect forehead points using Dlib/python

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, deep-learning, dlib

Do we have any way to get points on the forehead of a face image?

I am using 68 points landmarks **shape_predictor** to get other points on the face but for this particular problem I need
points that are from the hairline to the center of the forehead.

Any suggestions would be helpful.

Answer (score 2):

See this Github Repository: [shape predictor with forehead coverage](https://github.com/codeniko/shape_predictor_81_face_landmarks)

I was looking for a forehead area detection when I came across this 81 point predictor.
With some simple co-ordinate geometry calculations you can get all the points you have been looking for.

Comment: Welcome to SO! While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the tool provided with dlib called "imgLab" to train your own shape detector by performing landmark annotations